# Is there a way to store all arithmetic operators in just one variable to be used inside an output?

Tags: java

Instead of the variables **sum, diff prod** inside the 
**System.out.println(" " + **here**)**, is there a way I can store it in just one variable?

So if I call it inside a statement (and if i use a variable "answer")it would look something like this and will still give me the same output:

> ```
> System.out.println("Sum = " + answer);
> System.out.println("Difference = " + answer);
> System.out.println("Product = " + answer);
> ```

I'm really stuck at this part of the program, any kind of help or tips will do, thanks

Comment: How should this be possible? You call the same variable three times and expect three different results. The access to `answer` does not "know" anything about the string it gets concatenated with. **EDIT** even if it were possible (like it is in C++ by overriding the `+` operator), you would have to write the output always in the exact same order or add some more logic to the operator...

Comment: Dont get what youre asking for

Comment: Hmm, no you can't store multiple values in a single variable, can you give more details about what you are intending to do , maybe their is another way to achive it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array to store the `sum`, `diff`, and `prod` respectively.  Or you can great a new class that has those attributes.

For instance (with an array):

```
int[] answer = {sum, diff, prod};
System.out.println("Sum = " + answer[0]);
System.out.println("Difference = " + answer[1]);
System.out.println("Product = " + answer[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It can't work the way your example is stated, but you could do something like the following:

```
public class NumberPair {
    private final int x;
    private final int y;

    public NumberPair(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int sum() {
        return x+y;
    }

    public int difference() {
        return x-y;
    }

    public int product() {
        return x * y;
    }
}
```

Then you could do the following:

```
NumberPair answer = new NumberPair(10, 5);
System.out.println("Sum = " + answer.sum());
System.out.println("Difference = " + answer.difference());
System.out.println("Product = " + answer.product());
```

Comment: I'm doing the traditional java not object oriented java

Comment: There's no such thing, Java has been object oriented since it came out in 1996